# Fatal error Call to undefined method VmVendorPDF::convertHTMLColorToDec()

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I have updated the latest version of `Virtuemart 2.0.24c`, once the payment get completed it shows the below error

```
Fatal error Call to undefined method VmVendorPDF::convertHTMLColorToDec()
```

Comment: this simply means that `convertHTMLColorToDec` is an undefined function. Something you should really tell the VirtueMart dev team as it might be a small bug

Comment: @Lodder, thank you for the reply. Find the cause of issue, due to missing of latest ext_aio file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for the issue, updated the latest version of `ext_aio` file.

Extract the `ext_aio.tar` file and then make a `zip`, after that upgrade the pack, then it is working fine.

Reference Link:
http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=119484.0